# How to Get Archived User license using License Manager

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-license-manager, google-vault-api

Is there a way to read "Archived User" (AU) license using License Manager API? If so, please provide an example of the request. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! I posted an answer. Let me know if this solves your issue or if you need clarification about some point. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your response - it helped us resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

#### Retrieve specific user:

You can either retrieve the License for a specific user, using [LicenseAssignments: get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/get).

In this case, you'll have to make the following request to this URL:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/{productId}/sku/{skuId}/user/{userId}
```

Where:

- `productId` should be `101034` (productId for Archived User) (this ID is not officially documented and can only be indirectly retrieved using Reseller API, see **Documentation missing** section below).
- `skuId` would be `1010340001` for `Enterprise - Archived User` and `1010340002` for `Business - Archived User` (these IDs are not officially documented and can only be indirectly retrieved using Reseller API, see **Documentation missing** section below).
- `userId` would be the user's current primary email address.

#### List for product or for product and SKU:

If you don't want to retrieve a specific user, you can also list Licenses according to `productId` and `skuId`:

- [LicenseAssignments: listForProduct](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/listForProduct):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/{productId}/users?customerId={customerId}
```

- [LicenseAssignments: listForProductAndSku](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/listForProductAndSku):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/apps/licensing/v1/product/{productId}/sku/{skuId}/users?customerId={customerId}
```

#### Documentation missing:

Archived User `productId` and `skuId` are not currently documented in the [official API reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/how-tos/products). There is currently a feature request regarding a documentation update:

- [Enterprise License Manager API will not return G Suite Business/Enterprise Archived User licenses](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157926132)

I'd suggest you to star the issue in order to keep track of this and to help prioritizing its implementation.

#### Note on authorization:

Any of these methods would require getting authorized with the following scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.licensing`. I'm assuming you're not asking how to go through the [OAuth process](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/how-tos/authorizing), and you just need information on what methods to use.